# Syslog EJB Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I want all applications in a Glassfish server to have a single point on entry to the syslog output. I have found a library (https://github.com/CloudBees-community/syslog-java-client) that handles the Syslog output and I have made this work. But this required every application to have their own implementation of ILogger:

```
public interface ILogger extends Serializable {
    public void alert(String message);
    public void critical(String message);
    public void debug(String message);
    public void emergency(String message);
    public void error(String message);
    public void informational(String message);
    public void notice(String message);
    public void warning(String message);
    public void exception(Exception e);
}
```

So I want to have a bean that return implementations of this ILogger, something like this:

```
public interface ILoggerFacade extends Serializable {
    // beanName is the name of the bean requesting a Logger
    public ILogger get(String beanName);
    public void log(String beanName, int severity, String message);
}
```

So far my implementations result in exceptions:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionNoTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:638)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionBeanMgTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:467)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy528.getWlcById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:239)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at xxx.interfaces.domain.__IOrmFacade_Remote_DynamicStub.method1(xxx/interfaces/domain/__IOrmFacade_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at xxx.interfaces.domain._IOrmFacade_Wrapper.method1(xxx/interfaces/domain/_IOrmFacade_Wrapper.java)
    at xxx.test.QcastInterfaces.OrmFacadeTest.getApsByStatus(OrmFacadeTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at xxx.test.TestBackend.testMethod(TestBackend.java:95)
    at xxx.test.TestBackend.testClass(TestBackend.java:78)
    at xxx.test.TestBackend.test(TestBackend.java:62)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:75)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at xxx.logger.Logger.debug(Logger.java:34)
    at xxx.orm.beans.OrmFacadeBean.getWlcById(OrmFacadeBean.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor340.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor341.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
    ... 53 more
```

Implementations so far:

Logger

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Logger implements ILogger {
private final ILoggerFacade loggerFacade;
private final String bean;

public Logger(ILoggerFacade loggerFacade, String bean) throws NamingException {
    //this.loggerFacade = InitialContext.doLookup("java:global/QcastORM/logger/LoggerBean");
    //loggerFacade = null;
    this.loggerFacade = loggerFacade;
    this.bean = bean;
}

@Override
public void alert(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void critical(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void debug(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void emergency(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void error(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void informational(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void notice(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void warning(String message) {
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), message);
}

@Override
public void exception(Exception e) {
    // TODO stacktrace uitschrijven
    loggerFacade.log(bean, Severity.ALERT.numericalCode(), e.toString());
}
}
```

LoggerFacade

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@EJB(name = "samename", beanInterface = ILoggerFacade.class)
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@Remote
public class LoggerFacade implements ILoggerFacade {

    @Override
    public ILogger get(String bean) {
        // This is not ideal
        try {
            return new Logger(this, bean);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void log(String bean, int severity, String message) {
        // When this works, change syso into syslog
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

I have searched Google and SO but so far I haven't found any solutions I am happy with. My question is if I should think differently about this or an example of how this is accomplished.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your full exception and the implementation of the interfaces?

Comment: I have added them

Comment: Which method do you calling of LoggerFacade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you absolutely need to use that library, I'd recommend looking at [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch) or other libraries that support the [Simple Logging Facade for Java](http://www.slf4j.org). That will give you far more options and flexibility. The [Syslog Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) is available out of the box for Logback.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! How will it solve the problem I am facing?

Comment: It provides your programs with a single point of entry to syslog.You expressed an interest in alternate solutions -- this is the standard one for this situation, and simpler.